# DSolve cannot solve simple PDE?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

Laplace equation:

$\frac{\partial ^2u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$

with Dirichlet boundary conditions:

$u(0,y)=\sin (3 \pi  y)\\u(1,y)=0\\u(x,0)=0\\u(x,1)=\sin (4 \pi  x)\\(x,y)\in \Omega,\space\space\Omega=[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Following code returns sum of zeroes

```
DSolve[{
D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0,
u[0, y] == Sin[3*Pi*y],
u[1, y] == 0,
u[x, 0] == 0,
u[x, 1] == Sin[4*Pi*x]}, 
u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]]

(* {{ u[x, y] -> Inactive[Sum][0, {K[1], 1, ∞}] }} *)
```

I know closed-form solution

$u(x,y)=\frac{\sinh (3 \pi  (1-x)) \sin (3 \pi  y)}{\sinh (3 \pi )}+\frac{\sin (4 \pi  x) \sinh (4 \pi  y)}{\sinh (4 \pi )}$

Comment: Well, that's... strange.  This may be a bug;  what version of MM are you using?  (I can reproduce this behavior on MM 10.4.1 on a Mac.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I'm using 11 version. If I remember correctly, v10 DSolve cannot solve over the region

Comment: while `NDSolve` works perfectly...

Comment: well, i think we can consider it a bug.

Comment: I recommend that you send this to Wolfram, Inc as a bug to be fixed.  `DSolve` is a very buggy function, and we need to encourage Wolfram, Inc to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$Version
(* 11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017) *)
```

the code in the question now returns

```
(* Inactive[Sum]
   [Csch[Pi*K[1]]*DiscreteDelta[-3 + K[1]]*Sin[Pi*y*K[1]]*Sinh[Pi*(1 - x)*K[1]] + 
    Csch[Pi*K[1]]*DiscreteDelta[-4 + K[1]]*Sin[Pi*x*K[1]]*Sinh[Pi*y*K[1]], 
   {K[1], 1, Infinity}] *)
```

The nonzero terms correspond to `K[1] == 3` and `K[1] == 4`.  The simplest way to extract them is

```
(%[[1]] /. K[1] -> 3) + (%[[1]] /. K[1] -> 4)
(* Csch[3 π] Sin[3 π y] Sinh[3 π (1 - x)] + Csch[4 π] Sin[4 π x] Sinh[4 π y] *)
```

`Activate` also works but requires additional steps to simplify the result.

Evidently, the `DSolve` bug has been fixed for the code in question.

**Addendum**

As I noted in a comment on the answer by [David Baghdasaryan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/41483/david-baghdasaryan), `Piecewise` does not seem to function as one might hope when only one of two variables is included in its conditions.  This can be circumvented by including both variables, for instance by

```
Piecewise[{{Sin[3*Pi*y], x == 0 && 0 < y < 1}, {0, x == 1 && 0 < y < 1}, 
    {0, y == 0 && 0 < x < 1}, {Sin[4*Pi*x], y == 1 && 0 < x < 1}}, 0]
```

But, inserting this expression into `dcond` leads to the same nonsense answer that was cited in the original question.

```
(* {{u[x, y] -> Inactive[Sum][0, {K[1], 1, Infinity}]}} *)
```

I do not know whether this qualifies as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use DirichletCondition function to specify boundary conditions in this case. This is probably first solution:

```
 leqn = Laplacian[u[x, y],{x, y}] == 0;
dcond = DirichletCondition[
   u[x, y] == 
    Piecewise[{{Sin[3*Pi*y], x == 0}, {0, x == 1}, {0, 
       y == 0}, {Sin[4*Pi*x], y == 1}}, 0], True];
omega = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
(sol = FullSimplify@
   DSolve[{leqn, dcond}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] omega])
```

However, I still don't know why it is ignoring the second solution.

Comment: `Piecewise` is returning only the first expression, `Sin[3*Pi*y]` (for `x == 0`) and zero otherwise.  Reverse the order of the terms in `Piecewise`, and it will instead return only `Sin[4*Pi*x]` (for `y == 1`) and zero otherwise.