# Cannot Solve Simple PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I want to **solve** the partial differential equation $uu_{xy} = u_xu_y$. It is known that a solution is $u(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ for all pairs of (differentiable) functions $f$ and $g$ of one variable (Strauss Section 1.1 Problem 11).

This is what Mathematica 12 gives, which I'm unsure is correct since `DSolve`, etc. are seemingly [buggy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132276/dsolve-cannot-solve-simple-pde):

`DSolveValue[{u[x, y] D[u[x, y], x, y] == D[u[x, y], x] D[u[x, y], y]}, u[x, y], {x, y}]`
[image]

`NDSolveValue[{u[x, y] D[u[x, y], x, y] == D[u[x, y], x] D[u[x, y], y]}, u[x, y], {x, y}]`
[image]

Comment: `Simple PDE` This is not simple PDE. It is **non-linear** It requires finding first integral, then use that to convert the pde to set of ODE's. It is not always easy to find first integral of a PDE, in particular, a non-linear one.  Of course the question is asking to **verify**, and not to solve it. Big difference,. it is very easy to verify. Just plugin the assumed solution into the PDE. Mathematica can do this very easily. btw, what you wrote in Latex and what you wrote in the Mathematica code is not the same thing.

Comment: @Nasser Sorry, fixed the question. *I* want to solve the PDE.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. Do add it to others' questions if the issue has been verified to be a bug. See the tag description for details.

Comment: @Szabolcs Maple is able to solve it (screenshot in my answer below), so does it now indicate a bug of Mathematica?

Comment: @Leponzo I disagree that this is a bug. To call it a bug, we would need to have a reasonable standard by which differential equations should be considered solvable. There is no such standard for any complex symbolic algebra task, neither for DE solving, nor for integration. See Marius's link on your answer for many examples which are solved by Maple but not Mathematica, and also the reverse (solved by Mathematica only).

Comment: You can call it a missing feature if you like.

Comment: It's easy to solve by hand, too, by the way. (But, no, I do not think failure on a special case is a bug.)

Comment: Yes, I got confused with the terminology in this question (there it's a bug): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132276/dsolve-cannot-solve-simple-pde

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is missing a factor of `u[x, y]` on the LHS

```
eqn = u[x, y]*D[u[x, y], x, y] == D[u[x, y], x] D[u[x, y], y];
```

To verify that `f[x]*g[y]` is a solution to the equation use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
eqn /. u -> (f[#1] g[#2] &) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed the question. I want to **solve** the PDE.

Answer (score 1):

Maple is able to solve it, so it seems to be a bug in Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: No,it's not a bug.If Mathematica return input thats only mean that just doesn't know the answer.Maybe this will dispel any doubts ,see here:https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2020_and_mma_12_1/inse2.htm#x4-30001.2

Comment: Yes, I got confused with the terminology in this question (there it's a bug): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132276/dsolve-cannot-solve-simple-pde